# selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, api, selenium, automation

```
'    ct1 = df2[(df2['HomeTeam'] == at1)]['AwayTeamScore'].to_string(index=False)
result_away = np.round(ct1, decimals=3)'
```

output: '0.938031'

When executing the below code,

```
'javaScript1 = "document.getElementById('PoissonForm_homeGoalExp').value = result_away"'
```

output:

selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: result_away is not defined

How can I able to send the value as correctly defined as 'result_away'?

Comment: can you share the url of the page please

Comment: https://sinceawin.com/data/tools/poisson

Comment: So when I'm giving 'javaScript1 = "document.getElementById('PoissonForm_homeGoalExp').value = '0.938031'"' the digit as input I could able to get the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the javascript using `execute_script`.

```
javaScript1 = f"document.getElementById('PoissonForm_homeGoalExp').value = {result_away}"
driver.execute_script(javaScript1)
```